# how to create snapshot routine in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, snapshot, generated

I need help with a project to generate snapshot in AWS.

When generating a crontab it tells me that the crontab I typed is not valid. I need it to generate from Monday to Friday from 10 to 22 UTC, every 10 minutes.

Can anyone help me?

I tried this crontab:

```
0/10 10-22 * * MON-FRI *
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not quite clear your cron is running within your on-premise Linux-dist, or you are generating the cron in AWS native cloudwatch rule for snapshot. I believe the later scenario is more AWS-style. If yes, the correct syntax is 
0/10 10-22 ? * MON-FRI *
(It should be ? if you need any day of Month/Week)

Comment: Yes that's it, now it's working, thanks man, cron will run during the week and it will be inside CloudWatch, this syntax 0/10 10-22 ? * MON-FRI * working, Thank You so very much